# Deployment Fail During Generate Star Schema

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql

I am Using SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012 for Generating Start Schema.I am using one Database with four Tables.When i am Click on Start Button. I Got This Error

> The project could not be deployed to the 'THEONE\THEONE' server
>   because of the following connectivity problems :  A connection cannot
>   be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running. 
>   To verify or update the name of the target server, right-click on the
>   project in Solution Explorer, select Project Properties, click on the
>   Deployment tab, and then enter the name of the server.        0   0

How To solve This Error ?

Answer (score 0):

Do as it says , go to windows services and start the `SQL Browser` service.
You should be able to access it from SQL Server Configuration tools too.

Comment: Its already start and Firewall also Off.

Comment: It could be an access issue, try running Visual Studio as admin

Comment: That Process Already Done.But Not Work.